# Execute SQL-functions in R, Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc

I have a number of functions written on our Microsoft SQL servers.

I can easily access and query all data normally, but I cannot execute functions on the server using `RODBC`.

How can I execute sql-functions using R? Are there other packages that can do this?

Or do I need to switch strategies completely?

Example:

```
require(RODBC)
db <- odbcConnect("db")

df <- sqlQuery(channel = db, query = "USE [Prognosis] 
GO 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Functionname] ("information_variable")
GO" ) 

Error message:
"42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."                                                                                                               
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'USE... "
```

Comment: error says syntax error..?

Comment: The query is just an example really, the search works in sql-management studio, but does not work in R.

Comment: You may also want to look into the `RODBCext` package and its `sqlExecute` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to work:

```
df <- sqlQuery(channel = db, 
query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Functionname] ("information_variable")" )
```

So I dropped `USE [The_SQL_TABLE]` and `GO`